# Biblatex-Chicago: Comma after \Citetitle should appear before closing quotation mark

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

According to the Chicago Manual of Style, a comma should appear immediately before, not after, a closing quotation mark adjacent to it. This convention is known as "American-style punctuation." For example:

```
Please revisit “Stravinsky at His Bird-Best,” which represents the author at his finest.
```

However, as the following minimal example demonstrates, `biblatex-chicago` fails to produce the desired effect when the contentious comma follows a `\Citetitle` command:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
Author = {Craft, Robert},
Title = {Stravinsky at His Bird-Best},
Journaltitle = {Opera News},
Date = {1982},
Volume = {46},
Number = {8},
Pages = {14-15, 34}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Please revisit \Citetitle{test1}, which represents the author at his finest.

\end{document}
```

Indeed, the text in this case is incorrectly typeset as:

```
Please revisit “Stravinsky at His Bird-Best”, which represents the author at his finest.
```

Any ideas as to how to best patch the `\Citetitle` command (assuming that a patch is actually necessary)? `biblatex` provides the powerful `\mkbibquote` command, which supports American-style punctuation, but apparently `\Citetitle` does not utilize this facility:

Comment: The example works correctly for me. (with `biblatex-chicago.sty 2014/08/15 v 2.9a biblatex style` and `biblatex.sty 2014/06/25 v2.9a`

Comment: Which reminded me that I use a prerelease version of biblatex:

`biblatex-chicago.sty    2014/08/15 v 2.9a biblatex style` and 
`biblatex.sty    2014/09/28 v3.0 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)`

It could very well be a bug in the 3.0 version.

Comment: It might be worth to report it as a bug (though the biblatex maintainers are active in this site)

Comment: I just opened an issue on the [Biblateх repo](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/282) with a link to this page.

Comment: The issue has been confirmed and the devs are working on it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a pre-release version of biblatex.